# Get a user by username and password with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to do some extra checks on a user, I would like to get the user by username and password.

**Firstly:**

Is there a built in function that gets a user by username and password without authenticating them?

**Secondly:**

If the above is no, then how do I correctly hash the password, because if I use `Hash::make( $password )` and then compare to the database, it is not the same... You would usually use Hash::check but I need to actually get the user by username and password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First:**

If you want to check if user data to authentication is correct you can use:

```
if (Auth::validate($credentials))
{
    //
}
```

But if you want to get user from database with user and password, you can use:

```
$user = User::whereName($username)->wherePassword(Hash::make($password))->first();
```

**Second**

To store password in database you should use `Hash::make($password)` as you showed and it works without any problems. Using `Auth::validate` should solve the issue.

Comment: is $credentials an array?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Yes, you use it the same as `attempt` function but attempt will log user and this one won't

Comment: Hash::make($password) does not create the same password as is in the database (at least with Laravel 5.7). So this doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

**In Laravel 5.2**

You can use `Auth::once($credentials)` to validate credentials and thereafter `Auth::getUser();` to get the user.

```
$credentials = Request::only('username', 'password');
if(!Auth::once($credentials)) {
    // Invalid user credentials; throw Exception.
}

$user = Auth::getUser();
```

Comment: I like that this method doesn't require getting the User model involved to write a DB query, but I'm hesitant to use this, since the documents state the user is still authenticated as part of this process. Makes me wonder if I'm opening myself up to some potential issues down the road. After reading Laravel 8.x docs, I'm unable to find a better alternative, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a built in function you should use. I recommend you to read [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security). But here's a good example, it's pretty self-evident:

```
$input = array(
    'username'  => Input::get('username'),
    'password'  => Input::get('password'),
);

$remember = (boolean)Input::get('remember'); //'Remember me' checkbox

if (Auth::attempt($input, $remember)) {
    return Redirect::intended('dashboard')->with("success", "You're logged in!"); //Redirect the user to the page intended to go to, with the dashboard page as default
}
```

Registering a user looks something like this:

```
$input = array(
    'username'  => Input::get('username'),
    'email'     => Input::get('email'),
    'password'  => Hash::make(Input::get('password')) //Encrypt password
);

$user = User::create($input);
```

I also recommend you to read about [input validation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation). I hope this helps, good luck.

Edit: I didn't read the "without authenticating them" part. You should use `Auth::validate($input)` as Marcin already explained.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 You're responding to the wrong post ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.7

To check a users credentials without logging them in, I had to do this:

```
$user = User::whereEmail($request->email)->first();
$user = password_verify($request->password, optional($user)->getAuthPassword()) ? $user : false;
```

Laravel auth validation makes use of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php